# How does the allocation type in protocol buffer effect performance in different situation?

Tags: performance, protocol-buffers

Are there certain situations in which one allocation type in protocol buffer is preferred over the other in terms of performance?

I was looking on some discussion over the google groups, and it seems like persistent instance with Static allocation type will decrease cache miss. I am not familiar with the internals of the protocol buffer, can someone give some explanation on the subject?

Thanks

Comment: Which language are you using, and what do you mean by "allocation type"?